# The answer box should not be at the bottom

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, answers

The answer box is at the bottom of all answers. If someone has to answer a question he/she has to browse through all the previously written answers. 
If someone is interested to see others' answers then he can obviously browse, but for a question that invites a broad sense of views, all the answers might be different, and to someone who isn't interested in that of others has to first go through those of all others before posting their own answer.

So I feel that this should be modified.

Comment: Reading the other answers is what keeps the site from being junked up with redundant answers.  That's a benefit to all users, as I see it.

Comment: Your second sentence is likely the exact reason it's at the bottom.

Answer (score 24):

It should definitely be at the bottom. Suppose I have a brilliant answer in mind (granted, it does not happen that often), but upon reading the other answers, I see that my point is already covered in another answer (great minds think alike!). Does that mean I should still post my answer?

Comment: Yes, I agree to you.

But if there is a question say what problem ppeople face regarding their profiles, so before typing my problem I have to go through that of other and if there are already around 20-30 answers , I will have to browse through all of them.

Comment: @anshulsuri If there are 20-30 answers, that would make it seem *more* likely that someone's already made the point you were going to make, and it seems like it would be a pretty good idea to read them all. I sympathize; it sucks to have to go through that much text. But if you've arrived late to a discussion - well, you can learn a thing or two from reading what's already there. I always do. Even if someone hasn't said exactly what you were going to say, knowing what's been proposed so far *will* help you write a better answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for ur reply!!